# Acrobat: Sort attachments panel by location

Tags: adobe-acrobat, sorting, attachments

Using

- Adobe Acrobat XI Pro
- Windows 10 Pro 64 bit

In the attachments panel, the attachments are sorted by name by default. I can change the sort by clicking the heading of any of the columns, except location. When I click "Location", the list changes to a different order, but not by location. It appears that clicking on "Location" does the same thing as clicking on the last column heading that was clicked on.

[image]

How can I get the attachments panel to sort by location?

Comment: Which in this case would be by Name? What happens if you click it multiple times?

Comment: Yes, in the illustration, it would be "Name". But it could be any other column. And if I click it multiple times, then it reverses the order, just as if I had clicked that other column multiple times.